# Быстрое создание бинарного дерева поиска

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Как создать бинарное дерево поиска на `n` вершинах за `o(n^2)`? Дерево состоит из вершин, каждая вершина имеет указатель на левое и правое поддеревья и ключ.

Comment: а вы уверены что тут слово `быстрое` применимо?) Самый простой вариант - отсортировать сначала. Сложность `n log n` будет

Comment: Вы пытались создать его сами (например, [по описанию в википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0))? С какими проблемами Вы столкнулись? Если кто-то напишет Вам пример далеко не факт, что он подойдет для Вашей задачи.

Comment: @pavel это как раз худший случай

Comment: @asdf не совсем) вы сортируете и подвешиваете за середину. Потом края опять за середину. Ну вы поняли.

Comment: @defaultlocale ткните, пожалуйста, где в статье решена моя задача

Comment: например можно сделать n раз insert. В вопросе про балансировку ничего не сказано). Как раз в худшем случае квадрат будет.

Comment: @pavel да, а мне надо быстрее, в этом и вопрос

Comment: @asdf  я вам так скажу) с точки зрения олимпиадника - отсортированный массив - частный случай дерева. Поиск по нему делается бинарным поиском, что в точности совпадает с механикой работы дерева поиска. Если нужно именно дерево, то корень - центральный элемент. Потом всё что до корня - левое поддерево, после - правое. Повторять рекурсивно.

Comment: @pavel ок, но это не решение моей задачи; или вы хотите сказать, что такого алгоритма нет?

Comment: нет, я хочу сказать что ответ насколько короткий, что я его полностью написал в комментарии. Если хотите получить полный ответ, то покажите хотябы вашу структуру дерева .

Comment: посмотрите мой вариант дерева https://github.com/Semyon89/Dictionary

Comment: @asdf Для начала хотелось бы более подробного описания задачи, а то неясно в чем проблема. А так [вставка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0#.D0.94.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.8D.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B0_.28INSERT.29) в худшем случае O(n). Вставка n вершин будет O(n^2).

Comment: @pavel согласен, сейчас добавлю структуру в вопрос, формально вы правы, но у меня стандартная структура

Comment: @defaultlocale почитайте про разницу о малого и о большого

Comment: @СемёнШелухин я не нашёл там решения моей задачи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну какой вопрос - такой и ответ)

```
struct Tree{
     int value;
     Tree* left;
     Tree* right;
}

Tree* convertToTree(vector<int>& arr, int l, int r){  
   if (l >= r)
       return 0;
   Tree * tmp = new Tree;
   tmp.value = arr[(l+r)/2]; 
   tmp.left =   convertToTree(arr, l , (l+r)/2);
   tmp.right =   convertToTree(arr,  (l+r)/2+1 ,r);
   return tmp;
}

Tree* convertToTree(vector<int>& arr){
    arr.sort();
    return  convertToTree(arr,0,arr.size());
}
```

Comment: то есть для для `n!` вариантов будет одно и то же дерево?

Comment: @asdf почему бы и нет.

Comment: вот интересно, это псевдокод или у `std::vector` появился метод `sort` ??

Comment: @ampawd псевдокод. Я показал что нужно отсортировать именно вектор) Мне казалось так намерение более чёткое.

Answer (score 1):

В простейшем варианте -

```
struct Node
{
    Node *left, *right;
    int  value;
    Node(int value):value(value),left(nullptr),right(nullptr){}
};

void addNode(Node*&root, int v)
{
    if (root == nullptr)
    {
        root = new Node(v);
        return;
    }
    Node * cur = root;
    for(;;) {
        if (cur->value < v)
        {
            if (cur->right)
            {
                cur = cur->right;
            }
            else
            {
                cur->right = new Node(v); return;
            }
        } else {
            if (cur->left)
            {
                cur = cur->left;
            }
            else
            {
                cur->left = new Node(v); return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Работоспособность не проверял, но оно настолько просто, что... если что, подправите :)

Comment: это работает за `O(n^2)`

Comment: В **худшем** случае - да. В среднем - за `O(n log n)`

Comment: В стандартной терминологии, приводя ассимптотики, имеют в виду худший случай; + в комментариях я это ясно дал понять

Comment: Да сколько угодно. Не пойму только, почему при таком высоком уровне теоретических знаний простая практическая задача вызвала затруднения...

Comment: @Harry ну за линейно построить - уже не тривиальная задача) а вроде как возможно.

Comment: @pavel можете дать ссылку на линейное?

Comment: @asdf я точно знаю, что для декартового дерева это возможно. Но ссылку вот так сразу не найду. Но там не сильно красивый код.

Comment: @pavel ладно, если найдёте что-нибудь, скиньте тогда сюда